# Evento de clique no botão só é realizado uma vez no jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Então, tenho um botão que é gerado dinamicamente via AJAX.

Eu fiz um evento em jQuery que ao clicar no botão, é executado uma das condições que estão dentro do evento (nos IF e Else If).

Entretanto, o botão só executa um evento por vez. Se eu quiser clicar no botão novamente para ele realizar outro evento, o evento não acontece, ao menos que eu atualize a página.

Deixa eu tentar explicar melhor: 
Tenho um botão que mostra o Status da atividade, quando eu clico em outro botão "Reabrir Atividade", o status é pra mudar. E se eu clicar no botão "Reabrir Atividade" novamente, é por Status ser alterado novamente. Só que só está acontecendo a mudança uma única vez.

O que deveria acontecer:

Clicou no botão "Reabrir" (Status ia de Concluído para Iniciado), clicou no botão "Reabrir" Novamente (Status ia de Iniciado para Pendente).

Para ocorrer o fato acima, tenha que clicar em "Reabrir", Recarregar a Página, e clicar em "Reabrir" novamente.

Vou mostrar o código e uma imagem do sistema para ver se vocês conseguem ter uma noção.

```js
$(document).on("click",".REABRIRATIVIDADE", function(e){           
    var sts = $(this).attr('name');
    var codigo_empr = $(this).val();
    
    //PASSAR BOTÃO DE CONCLUIDO PARA INICIADO       
    if(sts == "CONCLUIDO")
    {
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").html("INICIADO");
        //andrews//////////////////////////////
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('background-color','rgb(236, 200, 70)');
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('border','1px solid gray'); 
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('color','royalblue');
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('font-weight','bold');
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('border-radius','5px');
    //andrews//////////////////////////////
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").attr('class', 'btn INICIADO');  
      
        var novo_status = "INICIADO";
        var reabrir = reabrirAtividade(sts, novo_status, codigo_empr);
        $('.REABRIRATIVIDADE').attr('name') = "INICIADO";
    }
    //PASSAR BOTÃO DE CONCLUIDO_VENCIDO PARA INICIADO_VENCIDO 
    else if(sts == "CONCLUIDO_VENCIDO")
    {
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").html("INICIADO_VENCIDO");
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('background-color','rgb(196, 95, 49)');
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('border','1px solid gray'); 
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('color','white');
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('font-weight','bold');
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('border-radius','5px');
        //andrews//////////////////////////////
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").attr('class', 'btn INICIADO_VENCIDO');  
  
        var novo_status = "INICIADO_VENCIDO"; 
        var reabrir = reabrirAtividade(sts, novo_status, codigo_empr);
        $('.REABRIRATIVIDADE').attr('name') = "INICIADO_VENCIDO";  
    }
    //PASSAR BOTÃO DE INICIADO PARA PENDENTE  
    else if(sts == "INICIADO")
    {
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").html("PENDENTE");
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('background-color','RoyalBlue');
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('border','1px solid gray');
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('color','white');
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('font-weight','bold');
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('border-radius','5px');
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").attr('class', 'btn PENDENTE');  
      
        var novo_status = "PENDENTE";
        var reabrir = reabrirAtividade(sts, novo_status, codigo_empr);  
        $('.REABRIRATIVIDADE').attr('name') = "PENDENTE";
    }
    else if(sts == "INICIADO_VENCIDO")
    {
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").html("VENCIDO");    
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('background-color','rgb(165, 42, 42)');
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('border','px solid gray');
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('color','white');
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('font-weight: bold;','bold');
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('border-radius','5px');
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").attr('class', 'btn VENCIDO');   
      
        var novo_status = "VENCIDO";
        var reabrir = reabrirAtividade(sts, novo_status, codigo_empr); 
        $('.REABRIRATIVIDADE').attr('name') = "VENCIDO"; 
    }
});
      


function reabrirAtividade(sts, novo_status, codigo_empr)
{
 
 $.ajax
 ({   
  url:"banco/pagina-minhas-tarefas/reabrir-atividades.php",  
  type:"POST",
  data:{sts:sts, novo_status:novo_status, codigo_empr: codigo_empr},
  async:false
  
 }).done(function(data)
 {     
  
 }).fail(function()
 {
  
 }).always(function()
 {
  
 }); 
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php

 date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

 // CHAMANDO O ARQUIVO DE CONEXÃO AO BANCO
 require_once("../conexao/conexao-com-banco.php"); 
 
 //CONSULTA NO BANCO QUE MUDA O STATUS NO BANCO DE DADOS 
  
 session_start();

 $usuario_reabrir_atividades = $_SESSION["nome"];
 
 $sts = $_POST['sts'];
 $novo_status = $_POST['novo_status'];
 $codigo_empr = $_POST['codigo_empr'];
 
 if($sts == "CONCLUIDO" OR $sts == "CONCLUIDO_VENCIDO")
 {
  $inserir_abrir_atividade = "UPDATE tbl_atividades SET STATUS = '{$novo_status}', DT_FIM = null WHERE codigo = $codigo_empr";
  $resultado_inserir_abrir_atividade = mysqli_query($conecta, $inserir_abrir_atividade);
 }
 
 else if($sts == "INICIADO" OR $sts == "INICIADO_VENCIDO")
 {
  $inserir_abrir_atividade = "UPDATE tbl_atividades SET STATUS = '{$novo_status}', DT_INICIO = null WHERE codigo = $codigo_empr";
  $resultado_inserir_abrir_atividade = mysqli_query($conecta, $inserir_abrir_atividade);
 }
 
 //SEGURANÇA - TESTANDO SE A QUERY FOI EXECUTADA
 if(!$resultado_inserir_abrir_atividade)
 {
  die("Erro no Inserte do Reabrir Atividade");
  
 }

?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter conseguindo explicar legal. 
Obrigado!

Comment: O name do seu botão nunca muda, então sempre vai cair na mesma condição do if. Talvez seja isso que esteja dando a impressão do evento não estar acontecendo

Comment: Eu fiz a inclusão dos "names" nos eventos. Porém não deu resultado ainda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como eu disse no comentário, você não estava alterando o atributo name do seu botão, por isso tinha a impressão de que o evento só era disparado uma vez. Você deve alterar esse name a cada click do botão, assim:

```
$(document).on("click",".REABRIRATIVIDADE", function(e){   
    var elemento = $(this);
    var sts = elemento.attr('name');
    var codigo_empr = $(this).val();

    //PASSAR BOTÃO DE CONCLUIDO PARA INICIADO       
    if(sts == "CONCLUIDO")
    {
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").html("INICIADO");
        //andrews//////////////////////////////
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('background-color','rgb(236, 200, 70)');
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('border','1px solid gray'); 
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('color','royalblue');
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('font-weight','bold');
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").css('border-radius','5px');
        //andrews//////////////////////////////
        $("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").attr('class', 'btn INICIADO');  

        //Altera o atributo name do elemento
        elemento.attr('name', "INICIADO");

        var novo_status = "INICIADO";
        var reabrir = reabrirAtividade(sts, novo_status, codigo_empr);
    }
    //...continuação da implementaçaõ dos else/if
});
```

Outro problema é que você está usando o `.attr()` para **ALTERAR** a classe do elemento, imagino que sua necessidade seja apenas mudar a classe dele para a próxima etapa, ou poderia também adicionar a classe `.REABRIRATIVIDADE` junto as outras, dessa forma:

```
$("tr#"+codigo_empr+" button.reabriratividade").attr('class', 'btn INICIADO REABRIRATIVIDADE');
```

Comment: JrD, não deu certo. Continua fazendo apenas um evento por vez.

Comment: @ThiagoPetherson Fiz a correção do código, dê uma analisada

Comment: obrigado. Sua observação foi ótima. Vc só colocou a classe errada ali. Colocou 'REABRIRATIVIDADE' e era 'reabriratividade'. Mas sua resposta já me ajudou muito mesmo assim. valeu!

Comment: JrD, deu um problema aqui. Quando eu filtro os Status, como por exemplo para só aparecer as Atividades com Status "CONCLUIDO" ou "CONCLUIDO_VENCIDO", a sua regra não funciona.

Comment: JrD. Quando eu carrego a página na primeira vez, funciona de boa. Porém, quando eu faço uma nova busca ou faço uma busca com filtro no Status, não funciona mais.

Comment: @ThiagoPetherson Você alterou a regra de adicionar classe nos outros if's?

Comment: Alterei sim. Conforme você tinha citado.

Comment: o problema é que a situação que mencionei só acontece na primeira vez que filtro com o botão "Buscar". Se eu filtrar novamente, a mudança de status não funciona quando clico no botão "Reabrir" (que muda os status).

Comment: Vem pro [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92253/evento-de-clique-no-botao-so-e-realizado-uma-vez-no-jquery) @ThiagoPetherson